# Arrange data in Dataframe based on dates

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, dataframe

Given the data of the form:

```
ID  Date     Highlight
1   201501   B
2   201506   C
1   201507   A
3   201508   D
2   201509   A
3   201510   B
3   201501   B
```

Required Output (in a dataframe) -- against every ID I need a sequence in order of the time of occurrence:

```
ID     Highlight Sequence
1      B, A
2      C, A
3      D, B, B
```

Essentially I intend to train a variable length input - RNN to predict the next character in the sequence against each of the IDs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) and [`sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) first:

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%Y%m')
df = df.sort_values(['ID','Date'])
print (df)
   ID       Date Highlight
0   1 2015-01-01         B
2   1 2015-07-01         A
1   2 2015-06-01         C
4   2 2015-09-01         A
6   3 2015-01-01         B
3   3 2015-08-01         D
5   3 2015-10-01         B
```

And then [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with parameter `sort`, because default sorting is not necessary with [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html):

... `list` for list column

```
df1 = df.groupby('ID', sort=False)['Highlight'] \
        .apply(list) \
        .reset_index(name='Highlight Sequence') \


print (df1)
   ID Highlight Sequence
0   1             [B, A]
2   2             [C, A]
1   3          [B, D, B]
```

... `join` for `string`s column:

```
df2 =  df.groupby('ID', sort=False)['Highlight']
         .apply(','.join)
         .reset_index(name='Highlight Sequence')

print (df2)

   ID Highlight Sequence
0   1                B,A
1   2                C,A
2   3              B,D,B
```

But if need order by position of rows (`date` column is sorted by default or is not important):

```
df2 = df.groupby('ID', sort=False)['Highlight'] \
        .apply(list) \
        .reset_index(name='Highlight Sequence') 

print (df2)
   ID Highlight Sequence
0   1             [B, A]
1   2             [C, A]
2   3          [D, B, B]
```